# countifs with an or statement - excel

Tags: excel, countif

I have a workbook where im referencing another workbook to count a certain number of items.

conditions:
1) col B has 11103,11104, or 11105 in it,
2) col F contains /2A DT

everything works fine if i just put 11103 in it, ive tried different permutations of the OR statement but cant find to find one that works, any suggestions? below is the formula:

```
=COUNTIFS('[all schools nfer log.xlsx VERSION 2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$B,OR('[all schools nfer log.xlsx VERSION 2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$B=11103,'[all schools nfer log.xlsx VERSION 2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$B=11104,'[all schools nfer log.xlsx VERSION 2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$B=11105),'[all schools nfer log.xlsx VERSION 2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$F:$F,"/2A DT")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding in your workbook names of course but a general outline of

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(B:B,{11103,11104,11105},F:F,"/2A DT"))
```

Which I guess would look like

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS('[all schools nfer log.xlsx VERSION 2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$B,{11103,11104,11105},'[all schools nfer log.xlsx VERSION 2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$F:$F,"/2A DT"))
```